# Entityframework.extensions error "Sequence contains more than one element" on batch delete

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using the EntityFramework.Extended library in my project, which contains a code first entity model.
I am receiving the error message "sequence contains more than one element" when I execute this linq statement and perform a batch delete from the library:

```
var subjLocal = (from subjectLocal in customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local
                         where ((subjectLocal.fkRosterSetID == 0) &&
                                (statsInfo.TestInstanceIDsList.Contains(subjectLocal.fkTestInstanceID)) &&
                                (subjectLocal.fkTestTypeID == statsInfo.TestTypeID) &&
                                (statsInfo.SchoolYearIDsList.Contains(subjectLocal.fkSchoolYearID)) &&
                                (subjectLocal.fkRosterTypeID == 1) &&
                                (subjectLocal.fkSchoolID == 0) &&
                                (subjectLocal.fkDepartmentID == 1) &&
                                (subjectLocal.fkCourseID == 1) &&
                                (subjectLocal.fkPeriodID == 1) &&
                                (statsInfo.DemoCatIDsList.Contains(subjectLocal.fkDemoCommonCategoryID)) &&
                                (statsInfo.DemoCodeIDsList.Contains(subjectLocal.fkDemoCommonCodeID)) &&
                                (statsInfo.TestSubjectIDsList.Contains(subjectLocal.fkTest_SubjectID)))
                         select subjectLocal.pkSummarySubjectLocalID).ToArray();

        if (subjLocal.Length > 0)
        {
            customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local.Where(s => subjLocal.Contains(s.pkSummarySubjectLocalID)).Delete();
            customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Bands.Where(s => subjLocal.Contains(s.fkSummarySubjectLocalID)).Delete();
            customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Averages.Where(s => subjLocal.Contains(s.fkSummarySubjectLocalID)).Delete();

            customerContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The error occurs at:

```
customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local.Where(s => subjLocal.Contains(s.pkSummarySubjectLocalID)).Delete();
```

customerContext is my base entity inheriting DBContext and RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local / _Bands / _Averages are a child tables. I am importing the library with a using reference and it notices the Delete() method so this works properly:

```
using EntityFramework.Extensions;
```

Isn't the purpose of the batch delete to make sure you can delete multiple items at once and shouldn't the sequence contain more than one element? Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find similar post [EntityFramework.Extensions 6.1 Batch Delete throws "Sequence contains more than one element"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386698/entityframework-extensions-6-1-batch-delete-throws-sequence-contains-more-than) here.

According to @deherech it seems to be a bug in Extension framework

Comment: So does this library not work at all then? Or can I just reinstall it or try stuff like that.

Comment: You may use .ToList() instead of .Delete()

Loop through the list and delete it individually. Like..

foreach(var item in list) item.Delete()